# Probability of adjacent pairs on an $N\times N$ board

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a question about the probability of finding adjacent pairs on a $N\times N$ board.

So there is a $N \times N$ cell surface and $M$ objects are randomly distributed on the surface. Each cell has a maximum of one object on it.

What is the expected value of the number of unique adjacent pairs of objects on the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2N(N-1)$ pairs of adjacent cells, and the probability for each such pair of neighboring cells to have objects in both of them is $\frac{M}{N^2}\frac{M-1}{N^2-1}$.

By linearity of expectations, the expected number of neighboring pairs of objects is
$$ 2N(N-1) \frac{M}{N^2} \frac{M-1}{N^2-1} = \frac{2M(M-1)}{N(N+1)}$$